# MongoDB/C# How to query a deeply nested array only?

Tags: c#, json, mongodb

I'm getting tired that I can't figure out(nor alone nor through SO) how to pull out deeply nested data within `BsonDocument` or custom classes directly. I know that I should use for sure a filter and a projection to get out an array/list of `Guid`s nested within another array.
Following is the structure(simplified):

```
//Thread
{
  Id: "B2",
  Answers: [
    {
      Id: "A1",
      Likes: [ "GUID1", "GUID2", "ETC" ] //<- this array, and only this.
    }
  ]
}
```

I have both the `Thread.Id` and `Answer.Id` as filtering data but then I tried with:

```
var f = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var filter = f.And(f.Eq("Id", ids.ThreadId), f.Eq("Answers.$[].Id", ids.AnswerId));
var projection = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include("Answers.Likes.$");
var likes = await dbClient.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(nameof(Thread))
    .Find(filter)
    .Project(projection)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

But this query always returns null, what I'm doing wrong from this POV?

Comment: I would change this to strongly typed objects and that way you can build your query using nothing but linq so you don't have to use things like Lies.$ or $[] and then try it.

Comment: With strongly typed objects I can't query/project straightforwadly array[].array[].array[]

Comment: @Eugene could you try: `var f = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var filter = f.And(f.Eq("Id", ids.ThreadId), f.Eq("Answers.Id", ids.AnswerId));
var projection = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include("Answers.Likes");
var likes = await dbClient.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(nameof(Thread))
    .Find(filter)
    .Project(projection)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();` I don't think $/$[] is required for C# driver.

Comment: @DipenShah Put like that also returns always null meanwhile I can see that the is in the DB

Comment: @Eugene are field names in the db same as mentioned in here? I mean, are they in the same case?

Comment: @DipenShah Yep, the driver by default uses the same fields to create DB entities as the C# classes so there isn't any difference from that POV

Comment: @Eugene interesting. Could you please also check if filter and projection are working individually? not in conjunction.

Comment: @DipenShah A projection cannot happen without a `Find()` meanwhile e `Find()` alone is ok but the result is still `null` :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222122/discussion-between-dipen-shah-and-eugene).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to project the individual fields from array in projection using regular queries.

You can at best project the matching element using regular queries and then map the likes.

Something like

```
var f = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var filter = f.And(f.Eq("Id", ids.ThreadId), f.Eq("Answers.Id", ids.AnswerId));
var projection = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include("Answers.$");
var answer = await dbClient.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(nameof(Thread))
    .Find(filter)
    .Project(projection)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Alternatively you can use filters with map using aggregation to match the answer element by id followed by projection to map the like field.

Something like

```
var f = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var match = f.And(f.Eq("Id", ids.ThreadId), f.Eq("Answers.Id", ids.AnswerId));

var project = new BsonDocument("newRoot", 
            new BsonDocument("$arrayElemAt", new BsonArray {
                new BsonDocument("$map", 
                    new BsonDocument
                        { 
                            { "input", 
                                new BsonDocument("$filter", new BsonDocument
                                    {
                                        { "input", "$Answers"},
                                        {"cond", new BsonDocument("$eq", new BsonArray { "$$this.Id", ids.AnswerId})}
                                    })
                            },
                            { "in", new BsonDocument("Likes", "$$this.UserLikes") }
                        }), 
                0}));    

var pipeline = collection.Aggregate()
.Match(match)
.AppendStage<BsonDocument, BsonDocument, BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument("$replaceRoot", project));

var list = pipeline.ToList();
```

Working example here - https://mongoplayground.net/p/wM1z6q92_mV

Comment: That mapping didn't work out, the bson is empty. Is it worth the effort in mongo DB to create complex documents but then being slayed by complex queries?

Comment: Fixed now - added example using query generated by driver  to verify the expected results.

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't able to fetch Likes with single filtering and projection. However, I was able to achieve it by using aggregation pipeline.

```
private async Task<BsonArray> GetLikes(string docId, string answerId)
{
    var client = new MongoClient();
    var idFilter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("ID", docId);
    var answerIdFilter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Answers.ID", answerId);
    var projection = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Exclude("_id").Include("Answers.Likes");
    var likes = await client.GetDatabase("test").GetCollection<BsonDocument>("items")
        .Aggregate(new AggregateOptions())
        .Match(idFilter)
        .Unwind("Answers")
        .Match(answerIdFilter)
        .Project(projection)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    return likes == null ? null
        : (likes.GetElement("Answers").Value as BsonDocument).GetElement("Likes").Value as BsonArray;
}
```

For some reason result included document in original structure as opposed to including just a document with `Likes` property so I had to do some post processing afterwards.

Comment: Still returns `null` :/
I put more detail in the chat if you're still interested.